# When $G'$/$G''$ and $G''$ both are cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There is a claim saying that if both $G'/G''$ and $G''$ are cyclic groups, then $G''=1$, where $G'$ is the derived subgroup of the group $G$. I have been thinking of this by focusing the N/C Lemma to clear the problem for myself. I need a useful igniting hint(s). Furthermore, may I ask: are these kinds of groups well known? Of course, any group satisfying the above conditions will be metabelian and obviously is soluble.

Comment: If $G'=\mathbb{Z}/4$ and $G''=\mathbb{Z}/2$ then $G'/G''=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: Or are $G',G''$ supposed to be subgroups of a larger group?

Comment: @Joe: your description is really right. I don't think  G′,G′′ need to be subgroups of any larger one.

Comment: $G''=Z_p$, $G'=Z_p\times Z_q$, $G'/G'' = Z_q$. ;-)

Comment: Are you sure $G'$ and $G''$ are not supposed to be $[G,G]$ and $[G',G']$? Otherwise, it is clearly not true.

Comment: What is $G'$ and what is a calim?

Comment: @Tobias: @Qiaochu: You are right.  G′ and G′′ are [G,G] and [G′,G'] reletively.

Comment: @Basil R: you should edit your title and question.

Comment: $G''=1$ is the same thing as saying $G'$ is abelian, so you're trying to prove that if $G'/G''$ and $G''$ are both cyclic then $G'$ is abelian.

Comment: @Gerry: You said what I exactly meant. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is theorem 9.4.2, page 146, in M. Hall's textbook on the Theory of Groups.

You are going in the right direction.  It uses the N/C theorem, as in, the normalizer modulo the centralizer is a subgroup of the automorphism group.

Another hint: It is very similar to showing "If G/Z(G) is cyclic, then G is abelian.".

---

These groups were known as "metacyclic groups" for a few decades, though the name is now used slightly differently.

A special case where G′ and G/G′ have coprime order is very special: these are exactly the groups in which all Sylows are cyclic.  They are also known as "Z-groups", though again the name means different things to different people.